# Custom HTTP Error 404 - Annotation based setting Spring 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, http-error

Is it possible to implement annotation based custom HTTP 404 error page using Spring 3.2.1?
I looked for ways in various forums but couldn't find any clear answer.

I also tried configuring using web.xml but it is not working when I access unmapped URL.
Any help please?

Log output

```
  7259 [DEBUG] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-test' processing GET request for [/spring-test/ss]
  7261 [DEBUG] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /ss
  7262 [DEBUG] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/ss]
  7262 [WARN ] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-test/ss] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-test'
  7262 [DEBUG] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="rest" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <!-- The definition of the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>main.java.net.bornil.config</param-value>
    </context-param>   

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>main.java.net.bornil.config</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file />
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors")
public class CommonExceptionHandler {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CommonExceptionHandler.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{code}")
    public ModelAndView handleException(@PathVariable int code) {

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("ERROR CODE IS: " + code);
        }

        return new ModelAndView("errors/404");
    }

}
```

Comment: If you directly go to /{yourContextPath}/errors/404, does it show the error page?

Comment: @Luciano yes. it shows the error page.

Comment: @Luciano I found the cause. Stupidly I made change in different web.xml. Now xml based configuration is working.  Any help about Annotation based configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution using annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've a simple webapp, single page and, after spending a morning on the Spring forum (so nice you cannot search '404' there because it's just 3 chars long) and Google this is the best solution I found.
Assuming you have a `index.jsp` and a `404.jsp`, my `@Configuration`' has:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    registry.addViewController("/*").setViewName("404");
}
```